# Find text which is not surrounded by any HTML tag

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a very unique requirement. I need to find out a text from a div which is not surrounded by any tag, then once I have it I need to surround it with a div and give it a CSS class.

For eg:

```
<div class="pagingCss" id="footer">
    <a href="/XXX/Home/Results?page=1">1</a>        
    <a href="/XXX/Home/Results?page=6">6</a>
    7 
    <a href="/XXX/Home/Results?page=8">8</a>        
</div>
```

So what I want my code to do is find this number 7 (in this case) and then surround it with a span tag and a class like:

```
<div class="pagingCss" id="footer">
    <a href="/XXX/Home/Results?page=1">1</a>        
    <a href="/XXX/Home/Results?page=6">6</a>
    <span class="someClass">7</span>
    <a href="/XXX/Home/Results?page=8">8</a>        
</div>
```

All this I am doing is beacuse I just cant get the spacing right for the tag less text and you can see in the screenshot attached

Link to the screenshot : http://yassershaikh.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/paging.png

Comment: Why don't you check and fix the server side code instead that renders the navigation?

Comment: A simpler solution would be to add the `a` tag to all the numbers and change the class on each anchor depending on if it should be selectable or not.

Comment: In fact, `7` is surrounded by a `<div>` tag. If you have to do it only on the pager, for text outside `<a>` (and not *any tag*), please be clearer.

Comment: Check my answer, hope this is what you need for your pagination.

Comment: I am using MVC 3 Razor WebGrid for this. And this is what my webgrid.pager() method renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
var footer = document.getElementById("footer");
var nodes=footer.childNodes;
for(i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
{
    if(parseInt(nodes[i].nodeValue)>0) 
    {
        var span = document.createElement("span")
        span.setAttribute("class","active");
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nodes[i].nodeValue));
        footer.replaceChild(span , nodes[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/RfveA/2/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load(){
var footer = document.getElementById("footer");
var toFind= "7"
for(i=0;i<footer.childNodes.length;i++)
if(footer.childNodes[i].textContent == toFind ){
var span = document.createElement("span")
span.setAttribute("class","someClass");
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(toFind));
footer.replaceChild( span , footer.childNodes[i] )
break;
}
}
</script>
<div class="pagingCss" id="footer">
<a href="/XXX/Home/Results?page=1">1</a>        
<a href="/XXX/Home/Results?page=6">6</a>7<a href="/XXX/Home/Results?page=8">8</a>        
</div>
<input type=button value="click" onclick="load()">
```

tested it .. makes the child `"7"` come under span..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
:not([href]){
 color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mfmHz/

Comment: Wow never knew this,

Can I use this with a particular class like
pagingCss:not([href]){}

Is that possible.